# Why Count(*) Over (Order By <column name>) can give a running toal?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with a column, and it has four records:

```
Create Table dbo.Test(Name varchar(100));
Insert into dbo.Test Values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D');
```

and then, the question is to have row number without using Row_Number windows function, so I use:

```
Select Name,(Select Count(*) Over (Order By Name,NewID() Rows Between Unbounded Preceding and Current Row) as RowNumber
From dbo.Test
```

and of course, it gives me the right answer, but could anyone explain a little bit, why this can have the row number. Because I do not use Partition By here, so the dbo.Test table should be one data set, and the RowNumber for each record should be the same which is 4. Please correct me and explain a little bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is in your question itself `_ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW_`, that basically means that for each row, the data set is up to the current row, so the count should be the *rownumber*.

if no **window frame preceding/following** is set, SQL uses exactly that window frame as you can see in the sample code below:

```
declare  @Test Table(Name varchar(100));
Insert into @Test Values ('A'),('B'),('C'),('D'),('1');

SELECT Name
 , (COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Name)) as RowNumberCorrect
, (COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Name ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) as RowNumberCorrect2
, (COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Name ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 FOLLOWING)) as RowNumberWrong
, (COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY Name ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)) as RowsCount
, (COUNT(*) OVER ()) as RowsCount2
FROM @Test
```